# Emscripten cpuid.h

Tags: c++, llvm, emscripten

Edit: Im trying to generate LLVM from a c++ project, not build the LLVM system itself.

I'm trying to build LLVM through emscripten, but I need the header 'cpuid.h'.

```
/home/emsdk-portable/emscripten/1.37.21/build/project/main.cpp:35:10: fatal error: 'cpuid.h' file not found
#include <cpuid.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
ERROR:root:compiler frontend failed to generate LLVM bitcode, halting
CMakeFiles/project.dir/build.make:86: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/project.dir/main.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/project.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:104: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/project.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/project.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:116: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

According [to this github](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten-fastcomp-clang/blob/master/lib/Headers/cpuid.h) cpuid.h should exist (Shouldn't it?) with the included clang, but neither I nor the program itself is finding it for the include.

[Fastcomp is the default backend](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/building_from_source/LLVM-Backend.html) and as such I thought cpuid.h should be locateable by whatever my program is.

Any ideas on finding/fixing the problems? Thanks